# Constructive handling of sequence numbers

Tags: haskell, newtype

I am implementing a simple protocol where messages have a sequence number that must increment strictly between messages. To handle this I wrote:

```
newtype SequenceNo = SequenceNo Int64
  deriving (Show, Eq)

validSequence :: SequenceNo -> SequenceNo -> Bool
validSequence (SequenceNo firstS) (SequenceNo secondS) = firstS + 1 == secondS
```

I use it something like this:

```
applyUpdates :: ProtocolState -> UpdateMessage -> Either String ProtocolState
applyUpdates oldState upd =
  if validSequence (seqNo oldState) (updSeqNo upd)
    then Right (ProtocolState {seqNo=updSeqNo upd, …})
    else Left "invalid sequence"
```

But this has the same problem of boolean blindness that `isJust :: Maybe a -> Bool` has. How do I do better?

Comment: I wouldn't consider `isJust` an example of boolean blindness. The return value directly answers the question implied by the function's name. A better example would be `filter`: do you *keep* each value that satisfies the predicate, or do you discard each one?

Comment: Why would `advanceSequence` in your answer take a potential return value as an argument? What's wrong with providing an `Enum` instance for `SequenceNo`, then defining `advanceSequence :: SequenceNo -> SequenceNo; advanceSequence = succ`?

Comment: The sending side is generating the sequence numbers, my code is only validating the numbers that I receive. What I mean about boolean blindness is that we usually prefer to write `case m of Just a → …; Nothing → …` instead of `if isJust m then … else …`.

Comment: That's still not boolean blindness; there's no confusion over what a return value of `True` *means*.

Comment: If you didn't already know what `filter` does, it would not be obvious from the type what it did. `filter :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]` is ambigous; `keepIfTrue :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]` is not, even with `Bool` in its type.

Comment: I don't insist on the terminology, maybe I should call it something else? What I'm getting at is that at the type level, we are not encoding the knowledge gained from the boolean, so the compiler cannot protect us from transposing the valid/invalid cases, or from using an unvalidated seqno.

Comment: That's a problem for whoever *uses* the boolean value, not the function that *generates* it, and you haven't said who will use `validSequence`.

Comment: Ignoring your answer, what is the problem with a simple type isomorphic to `Bool`, `data Valid = Valid | Invalid`? Then `validSequence :: SequenceNo -> SequenceNo -> Valid; validSequence (SequenceNo x) (SequenceNo y) = if x + 1 == y then Valid else Invalid`.

Comment: I added a usage example to give more context to my code snippet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just define a type isomorphic to `Bool`, but with more descriptive constructor names.

```
date Validity = Valid | Invalid
```

then write a function that returns the *kind* of sequence represented by the arguments:

```
classifySequence :: SequenceNo -> SequenceNo -> Validity
classifySequence (SequenceNo x) (SequenceNo y) | x + 1 == y = Valid
                                               | otherwise = Invalid
```

It's even simpler if you define an `Enum` instance for your type.

```
newtype SequenceNo = SequenceNo Int64 deriving (Show, Read, Eq, Enum)

classifySequence :: SequenceNo -> SequenceNo -> Validity
classifySequence x y | succ x == y = Valid
                     | otherwise = Invalid
```

Either way, you can define

```
applyUpdates :: ProtocolState -> UpdateMessage -> Either String ProtocolState
applyUpdates oldState upd =
  case validSequence (seqNo oldState) (updSeqNo upd) of
    Valid -> Right (ProtocolState {seqNo=updSeqNo upd, …})
    Invalid -> Left "invalid sequence"
```

although you might consider an explicit error type as well:

```
data SequenceError = InvalidSequence

applyUpdates :: ProtocolState -> UpdateMessage -> Either SequenceError ProtocolState
applyUpdates oldState upd =
  case validSequence (seqNo oldState) (updSeqNo upd) of
    Valid -> Right (ProtocolState {seqNo=updSeqNo upd, …})
    Invalid -> Left InvalidSequence
```

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this:

```
data SequenceTag = Initial | Following

newtype SequenceNo (t :: SequenceTag) = SequenceNo Int64
  deriving (Show, Eq)

advanceSequence ::
    SequenceNo 'Initial ->
    SequenceNo 'Following ->
    Maybe (SequenceNo 'Initial)
advanceSequence (SequenceNo firstS) (SequenceNo secondS)
  | firstS + 1 == secondS = Just (SequenceNo secondS)
  | otherwise = Nothing
```

Usage:

```
applyUpdates :: ProtocolState -> UpdateMessage -> Either String ProtocolState
applyUpdates oldState upd =
  case advanceSequence (seqNo oldState) (updSeqNo upd) of
    Just s -> Right (ProtocolState {seqNo=s, …})
    Nothing -> Left "invalid sequence"
```

Better, but still a bit clunky?

Comment: See my comment on the question; the fact that you switched from `validSequence` to `advanceSequence` suggests you have an XY problem.